# Metamorph error when trying to save record

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit

I'm getting a strange error when I'm trying to save some data.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.
```

I've noticed something weird in the actual DOM

```
<h1>Posts page</h1>
<script id="metamorph-2-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
<script id="metamorph-2-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
<p>...</p>
...
<button data-ember-action="5" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</button>
<script id="metamorph-2-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover>
```

There are two of the same metamorph tags and only one end tag. I've also tried not using the partial (ie having the code sit in the dom). While the duplicate metamorph start tag disappears, when trying to save, the metamorph tag its trying to reference doesn't exist.

[Here is a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/oxEPOXO/2/edit) of my code. the JSBin works, which is promising. The only difference between the jsbin and my code is that I'm using [Ember App Kit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit). My guess is I'm doing something wrong with the ES6 setup. I've posted my controller code here

```
var IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  addingNew: false,
  actions: {
    createAccount: function() {
      var account = this.store.createRecord('account', {
        name: 'howdy',
      });
      account.save();
    },
    showNew: function() {
      this.set('addingNew', true);
    },
    cancelNew: function() {
      this.set('name', '');
      this.set('addingNew', false);
    }
  }
});

export default IndexController;
```

What am I doing wrong to get this error?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this before when I have html comments enclosing ember tags.  Something like:

`<!-- {{#if something}}X{{else}}Y{{/if}} -->`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have seen that suggested elsewhere. Unfortunately in my case there are no comments anywhere. For now I've worked around the problem by creating an object in an objectcontroller rather than a partial interfacing with the arraycontroller